# Вывести значение переменной возле скрытого поля

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть 2 скрытых поля, с `type="hidden" name="a" value="<?=rand(1, 100)?>` и
`type="hidden" name="b" value="<?=rand(1, 100)?>`.

Как рядом с полями вывести значение a и b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$valueA = rand(1, 100);
$valueB = rand(1, 100);
?>
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?php echo $valueA; ?>" />
    <div class="value-display">
        <?php echo $valueA; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="<?php echo $valueB; ?>" />
    <div class="value-display">
        <?php echo $valueB; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(rand(1, 100), rand(1, 100));
value="<?=$arr[0]?>" и value="<?=$arr[1]?>"
```

Так же и рядом с полями :)